# DNS: forward part of a managed domain to one host, but sub domain services to another (Google Apps)

Tags: email, dns, google-workspace, web-hosting, domains

I was going to post this as a comment against [DNS: Forward domain to another host](https://superuser.com/questions/411262/), but I don't seem able to do that.

I'm in a similar situation. I have a DNS registered/managed by enom, except with the slight twist that the domain was originally registered with enom through a Google Apps account creation. The domain currently supports a Google Apps site/account.  I now want to direct the bare primary domain and `www` entries to a hosting provider for the website component, but leave the Google Apps setup intact for its services such as calendar, mail etc. For now, I'm leaving the domain managed by enom.

Also note that when I registered my account with the hosting provider, I gave the same domain name as the existing domain (e.g. `example.com`), so at their end I'm working with the same domain name in cpanel, etc.

In my case, the existing enom DNS entries don't have an A record for the `www.example.com`, or the bare `example.com` domain.  Instead, there are 4 x @ records with the Google Apps IP Address, 2 x TXT records with what I assume are Google Apps site verification strings/tokens, and a bunch of CNAME records for the various features of Google Apps (mail, calendar, docs, sites, etc).

So, my questions:

- How do I point the `www.example.com` and `example.com` DNS entries at enom to my web site hosting provider, while leaving the domain managed by enom, and the Google Apps services working as they are now (with the obvious exception of Google Sites)?
- How do I setup the `example.com` mail-related DNS records (MX, etc) at the web site hosting provider, so that outbound email to `any_name@example.com` gets correctly sent to the google apps mail account, and doesn't get trapped inside the *pseudo domain* within the hosting providers servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CNAME **www** should be pointing to your A RECORD **@**. Your A RECORD **@** should be pointing to your hosting server's IP. And you should have the required MX RECORDS for Google Apps.

My GoDaddy Zone File looks something like this:

**A (HOST)**

HOST, POINTS TO

```
@, 000.00.00.00
```

**CName (Alias)**

HOST, POINTS TO

```
www, @
```

**MX (Mail Exchanger)**

PRIORITY, HOST, POINTS TO

```
5, @, ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

5, @, ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

1, @ ,ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

10, @ ,ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

10, @, ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

Hope this helped

Comment: belated thanks for responding - yes: that's helpful

Comment: Beter later than never Paul :P